# How do you correctly set the PYTHONPATH variable on Windows?

Tags: python, django

Whenever I try to expirement with Python on Windows, I always run into a wall with the import statements.  Python simply can't find anything on Windows -- every import, even for something as core as timezone fails.

I know this has something to do with the PYTHONPATH environment variable.  In my case, Python is installed to "C:\Python27".  My PYTHONPATH looks like this:

```
C:\Python27;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib
```

Still, nothing will import.  I get errors like this:

```
File "D:\Code\Django\polls\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.utils import timezone
ImportError: cannot import name timezone
```

What's wrong with my situation?

Comment: How did you install Django on Windows?

Comment: Have you added python to PATH not python path. You need to add c:/pyhon27 to your path. Also, see the above comment.

Comment: Django on Windows: http://www.helicontech.com/articles/running-django-on-windows-with-performance-tests/

Comment: It sort of looks like you didn't get all of Django installed. What happens if you do this from a Python shell: `>>> import django; print django.__file__`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the official docs on [using Python on Windows](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html), in particular the section on [finding modules](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#finding-modules).

You have to add the directory where you installed 3rd party modules to your `PYTHONPATH` if you didn't install them to your `Python27\Libs\site-packages` directory.

Another option is to get acquainted with [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) and [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). These tools make installing 3rd party modules a breeze. Although I don't know how well they are supported on Windows (I mainly do Python development on Linux).

Answer (score 2):

`PYTHONPATH` = If this variable exists in your environment, Python will add it to the normal search path for modules when you use any import statement; you normally *do not modify this* as well behaved Python scripts will install themselves in the `site-packages` directory, and Python searches this by default.

`PATH` = this is the global file system path. Your operating system will search the directories listed in this variable (from left to right), to find commands when you type something at a command prompt.

In order for Python to work correctly only Windows, the `C:\Python27` directory should be listed in `PATH`. If you ran the installer as an Administrator, the installer will modify the ***global*** `PATH` and add this for you. If you installed it as a normal user, you need to modify the `PATH` manually.

To add this manually, right click on `My Computer` and select `Properties`. Click on `Advanced`, then `Environment Variables`. You'll see two boxes - `User Variables` and `System Variables`. You can only edit user variables - system variables need administrative access.

Simply add a new variable (or modify the existing `PATH`)  You should also add `C:\Python27\Scripts` to your `PATH` as most commands installed by Python scripts (like django-admin.py) are installed here. Directories are separated by `;`

Once you have done this; python should work properly for you on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

virtualenv is good option.
else simply add site-packages in path.

Comment: "Add site-packages in path". Everything in site-packages is already put on the Python path.